# Loop gdal_translate in Mac OS Terminal

Tags: gdal

I'm working with a large dataset of sentinel2 images (jp2 format) and I want to convert them to Gtif format using the comand gdal_translate. I want to create a loop to perform this task. I'm working on Terminal Mac OS 10.12.3 and my GDAL version is 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24.  When doing it one by one, it works using this code

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff /path/to/input/S2_b1.jp2      
/path/to/output/S2_b1converted.tif
```

By the moment I have tried:

```
cd /path/to/working/directory for f in *.jp2 do gdal_translate -of GTiff
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) terminal on your Mac, your script would be something like this:

```
cd /home/user/working/directory;

for file in *.jp2
do
    gdal_translate -of GTiff /path/to/input/$file /path/to/output/${file%.jp2}.tif --config GDAL_SKIP JP2ECW
done
```